# Execute function from S3 downloaded JavaScript file without creating a local file on disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ecmascript-6

Assume that we download the script below from `S3`:

```
const sum_two = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
}
```

Downloading using this:

```
async function downloadFileS3(filenameDownload) {
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const fs = require('fs');

    AWS.config.update(
        {
            accessKeyId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            secretAccessKey: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
            correctClockSkew: true,
        }
    );

    const params = {
        Bucket: 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
        Key: filenameDownload,
    }

    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    try {
        const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
        if (data) {
            // do something with data.Body      
            const downloaded = data.Body.toString('utf-8');
            // grab sum_two from "downloaded" and use below 
            
            .......
            .......
            .......
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}
```

How can we extract `sum_two` (and use it afterwards) from `downloaded` WITHOUT creating a local file ?

Meaning I don't want to use the code below !!!

```
// fs.writeFile(`${filenameDownload}`, downloaded, function (err) {
//    if (err) {
//         console.log('Failed to create file', err);
//    }
// console.log(sum_two(.... , ....));
// });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use node.js native [vm](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module for this.

Create a `Script` from the downloaded code

Run it in the current context

After that the downloaded function will become available for usage:

```
const vm = require('vm');

// ...

const downloaded = data.Body.toString('utf-8');
const script = new vm.Script(downloaded);
script.runInThisContext()
console.log(sum_two(1,2))
```

Comment: But how do we get `sum_two` from `script` ?

Comment: Since we run the script in `this` context `sum_two` function is registered in the surrounding lexical environment. So we can use it right after `runInThisContext` call

Comment: Amazing , didn't know about that.Thanks!